# VBA Access - Not setting focus on field

Tags: vba, ms-access

Im making a Sub to check data of the field but after the error the Field is not setting focus on the field!

```
Private Sub txtOpenWindow_LostFocus()
On Error GoTo TrataErro
Dim strSQL As String
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
    strSQL = "select HORARIO from tblTipoHorario where Horario = #" & Me.OpenWindow & "#"

    Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
    With rst
         .ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
         .CursorType = adOpenKeyset
         .LockType = adLockOptimistic
         .Source = strSQL
         .Open
    End With
    If Not rst.EOF Then
        MsgBox "Este Horario não pode ser utilizado para uma janela de programação comum!", vbOKOnly, "Brain"
        Me.Undo
        Me.txtOpenWindow.SetFocus
    End If
Exit Sub
TrataErro:
    MsgBox "Encontrado um erro no processo. " & Chr(13) & "Entre em contato com a área de TI e informe os dados abaixo. " & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & _
           "Mensagem: " & Chr(13) & Err.Description & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & "Objeto: " & Me.Name & " - OpenWindow_LostFocus", vbExclamation, "BRAIN - Alerta"
    RegistraLog "OpenWindow_LostFocus", Me.Name, "Erro: " & Err.Description
End Sub
```

Comment: Try doing this in the `AfterUpdate` event instead of `LostFocus`

Comment: Data validation is usually done in BeforeUpdate event.

Comment: @June7 thanks worked!!!!